# Porting nginx as a mountain lion bundled app

Tags: xcode, nginx, porting, osx-mountain-lion, app-bundle

I was wondering how difficult it would be to create an app bundle from the sources of nginx. Since mountain lion, the apache webshare option has been removed and i can imagine that some people would like a gui frontend that will start/stop nginx, and perhaps even with configuration directives like radio buttons etc.

Now this could be a panel or a stand alone app. I have been searching on a "best practice" manner to do this kind of thing but came up with all kinds of hacks.

I feel it would be cool to build the whole thing inside xcode with all libs bundled. So question, how to take on a pet project like this? Any suggestions? 
;-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [MNPP](http://getmnpp.org/)?

Here is source code for it https://github.com/jyr/MNPP